How do I center align alt text in quarto
I am adding an image in quarto. How do I center align the alt text and also reduce the font. See Image below added in quarto using ![](png/skim.png){width=90% fig-align=center}

How can I center align the "Data Summary" text and also reduce the font size?

There is no alt text in your code. Please share codes that reproduce the issue you are stating.
